# MySQL return rows when count(*)=0

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Table **users**:

```
userId, user
------------
0, Alice
1, Bob
2, Eve
```

Table **rss**:

```
userId, link, read
------------
0, example.com/1, 0
0, example.com/2, 1
0, example.com/3, 1
0, example.com/4, 0
1, example.com/3, 0
1, example.com/4, 1
```

When I run:

```
SELECT `users`.`user`, COUNT(*) FROM `rss` INNER JOIN `users` ON `rss`.`userId`=`users`.`userId` WHERE `rss`.`read`=0 GROUP BY `rss`.`userId`
```

I get:

```
Alice, 2
Bob, 1
```

But I would like to also have Eve mentioned (stating 0), i.e.,

```
Alice, 2
Bob, 1
Eve, 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an outer join:

```
SELECT u.`user`, COUNT(rss.userId)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     rss
     ON rss.userId = u.userId AND rss.`read` = 0
GROUP BY u.userId;
```

And, I made the following changes:

- Add alias for `users` so the query is easier to read and write.
- Switched the tables so I could use `left join` instead of `right join`.  I think `left join` is easier to read.
- Changed the `group by` to use the field from the `users` table.
- Moved the condition on `rss` to the `on` clause.
- Removed most of the back ticks.  They just clutter the query.